Wake-on-Lan via WiFi, or force all other network traffic via WiFi
What I'm trying to achieve: I need to be able to wake my pc remotely using a magic packet. I also like to stream games via Steam Remote Play so I can play on my laptop in another room.
The problem: I recently moved, and the layout of this place means running an ethernet cable to my study is not very practical. I've tried using a powerline adaptor, but this place has old wiring, and the throughput isn't good enough to stream. I have a solid WiFi setup using Ubiquiti gear, have been streaming connecting through the WiFi network, but then I can't wake my PC remotely anymore.
What I've tried: I've tried having the ethernet still plugged in, but Steam seems to always stream via it even though the WiFi has lower latency and higher throughput. I've tried setting the WiFi to having a higher interface metric (no luck). I've tried using ForceBindIP, but Steam opens a different client for streaming so that didn't work.
Does any one have any potential ideas on how to solve this? Whether it's a case of WoL over WiFi (which in my research doesn't seem possible?), or some other way to effectively disable the ethernet for all traffic other than a magic packet? Is there maybe a solution via UniFi?

a higher interface metric - try a LOWER one - networking 101 (or a HIGHER one for ethernet)
